Computing the different of an order $\mathcal{O} \subset \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_9]$
Consider the cyclotomic field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_9)$. There is a totally real subfield $K_0 = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ of $K$ where $\alpha = \zeta_9 + \zeta_9^{-1}$. Let $\mathcal{O}_{K_0}$ be the ring of integers of $K_0$ with the following $\mathbb{Z}$-basis, $\{ 1, \alpha, \alpha^2 \}$. Write $$\mathcal{O}_K = [1, \eta]_{\mathcal{O}_{K_0}} = [1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \eta, \eta\alpha, \eta\alpha^2 ]_{\mathbb{Z}}$$ as a rank-$2$ $\mathcal{O}_{K_0}$-module, (resp. as a rank-$6$ $\mathbb{Z}$-module), where $\eta = \frac{\alpha + \sqrt{D}}{2}$ with $D = \alpha^2 - 4$ representing the discriminant of $f(X) = X^2 - \alpha X + 1\in K_0[X]$. Consider now an order $\mathcal{O} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$, where $$ \mathcal{O} = [1, \ell\eta]_{\mathcal{O}_K} = [1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ell\eta, \ell\eta\alpha, \ell\eta\alpha^2 ]_{\mathbb{Z}} $$ with $\ell$ prime.
Using the $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $\mathcal{O}$ above one compute (by using MAGMA, e.g.) a basis of the dual ${\mathcal{O}^\vee}$, as $$ \frac{1}{9}( 5 - 2 \alpha^2 + \ell \eta - \ell \eta \alpha^2),\\ \frac{1}{9}(-2 \alpha + \alpha^2 - \ell \eta \alpha + 2 \ell \eta \alpha^2),\\ \frac{1}{9}( -2 + \alpha -  \ell \eta + 2 \ell \eta \alpha ),\\ \frac{1}{9 \ell}( 1 - \alpha^2 - 6 \ell \eta + 2 \ell \eta \alpha + 2 \ell \eta \alpha^2 ), \\ \frac{1}{9 \ell} (- \alpha + 2 \alpha^2 + 2 \ell \eta - 4 \ell \eta \alpha),\\ \frac{1}{9 \ell} ( -1 + 2 \alpha + 2 \ell \eta - 2 \ell \eta \alpha^2 ).$$ We define the different of $\mathcal{O} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ to be the integral ideal $$ \mathfrak{D}_{\mathcal{O}} = \{ x\in K : x \mathcal{O}^\vee \subset \mathcal{O}\} .$$
Question: How can I compute $ \mathfrak{D}_{\mathcal{O}}$ using MAGMA? Thank you.

There is a built-in different function in MAGMA.
Different(Integers(CyclotomicField(9)));


Hi Victor and thank you for your answer; I checked the Magma-Documentation and this is what it says: "The different of the maximal order O."
In my case the order is not-maximal and I can't use it. I have to solve a system of equations which I am planning to add here in the next days.

@Adrian it should work for non-maximal orders as well as shown in https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/411#4136 .
